# How to execute this F# function

Tags: f#

I tried to execute the following function in multiple ways, but it was always in error.
So how do i execute constructQuery :

```
type PersonName =
| FirstOnly of string
| LastOnly of string
| FirstLast of string * string

let constructQuery personName = 
    match personName with
    | FirstOnly(firstName) -> printf "May I call you %s?" firstName
    | LastOnly(lastName) -> printf "Are you Mr. or Ms. %s?" lastName
    | FirstLast(firstName, lastName) -> printf "Are you %s %s?" firstName lastName
```

-edit-.

I have tried calling the function like this:

```
constructQuery "himekami"
constructQuery ("himekami" : PersonName.FirstOnly)
constructQuery PersonName.FirstOnly("himekami")
```

and error produced was like this :

```
Analyzer.fs(12,17): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
PersonName
```

but here has type
    string

This is because i don't quite understand the way "type" in F# works.

Comment: Please edit the question to explain what ways you've tried and what errors you get.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess the question is how to construct `PersonName` objects (as those are the input for your function).

This is quite easy - just use one of the constructors `FirstOnly`, `LastOnly` or `FirstLast`:

```
let firstOnly = FirstOnly "Tom"
let lastOnly  = LastOnly "Hengs"
let firstLast = FirstLast ("Tom", "Hengs")
```

and you can use them like this:

```
constructQuery firstOnly
constructQuery lastOnly
constructQuery firstLast
```

### background

You see `PersonName` is an algebraic datatype with it's 3 constructors and the `constructQuery` matches it's only parameter for them. In VisualStudio (or MonoDevelop) you should be able to get a tooltip with the types for each part of this - you should do this all the times, because types are a big part understanding.

### other Ways to call this function

you can use the pipe-operator `|>` and do this in one go:

```
FirstOnly "Tom"
|> constructQuery
```

of course you can use it without this operator too:

```
constructQuery (LastOnly "Hengs")
```

but here you need the parens because without them you would plug the **function** `LastOnly` (and yes this is a function `String -> PersonName`) into the function `constructQuery` and then apply the string like this:

```
constructQuery LastOnly "Hengs" = (constructQuery LastOnly) "Hengs" // error: compiler complains about mismatched types
```

because `LastOnly` is really a function (sadly this is not the case for C# constructors) you can do cool stuff like this too:

```
// Pipes all the way
"Hengs" |> LastOnly |> constructQuery

// this is another function String -> PersonName
let constructFromLastOnly = LastOnly >> constructQuery

// you can call it like this
constructFromLastOnly "Hengs"

// etc. ... imagine
```

another alternative is to use the backwards pipe `<|` (not so idiomatic):

```
constructQuery <| LastOnly "Hengs"
```

where you don't need the parens either

### Remarks

I would encourage you (even if the compiler don't really needs it) to give the types for top-level functions (thouse you want to use from other parts of your program):

```
let constructQuery (personName : PersonName) : () =
   match personName with
   // ...
```

Did you see that you don't really need `personName` besides the call to `match`?
This is so common that there is another/shorter way to write this:

```
let constructQuery = function
    | FirstOnly(firstName) -> printf "May I call you %s?" firstName
    | LastOnly(lastName) -> printf "Are you Mr. or Ms. %s?" lastName
    | FirstLast(firstName, lastName) -> printf "Are you %s %s?" firstName lastName
```

or with a signature:

```
let constructQuery : PersonName -> () = 
    function
    | FirstOnly(firstName) -> printf "May I call you %s?" firstName
    | LastOnly(lastName) -> printf "Are you Mr. or Ms. %s?" lastName
    | FirstLast(firstName, lastName) -> printf "Are you %s %s?" firstName lastName
```

And finally - I don't like the fact that you mix `printf` in there.
See a function returning unit `()` is never pure and you mix concerns. Why not like this:

```
let constructQuery : PersonName -> string = 
    function
    | FirstOnly(firstName) -> sprintf "May I call you %s?" firstName
    | LastOnly(lastName) -> sprintf "Are you Mr. or Ms. %s?" lastName
    | FirstLast(firstName, lastName) -> sprintf "Are you %s %s?" firstName lastName
```

and use it like this:

```
FirstOnly "Tom"
|> constructQuery
|> Console.WriteLine
```

so you can *reuse* it for example in a WPF app or in a logging scenario where the console is not avaiable.

Comment: This is good. feels like personally tutored. Thank you very much.

Comment: np - was in the mood ;) - Just ask - we need way more F#ers out there :D